# Telnet command by vbs

Tags: vbscript, telnet

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

by pass it like:

```
cloner.SendKeys"netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled"
```

But I got error: Expected end of statement.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VbScript, you need to use 2 double quote characters to include a double quote character in a string:

```vb
cloner.SendKeys "netsh interface set interface name=""Local Area Connection"" admin=disabled"
```